# Serilog show the property name in the output

Tags: c#, serilog

If I have this:

```
logger.Information("this is a message with {property_name}", "value");
```

Ho do I output this:

```
this is a message with property_name = value
```

instead of:

```
this is a message with value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The display output of log messages written via Serilog is done by the [formatter](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output) used by the Sink that you are writing to. Each sink can use a different formatter and can represent outputs differently.

What you are asking for is not something that the default formatters can do, so you would have to write your own [custom text formatter](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#custom-text-formatters), and then tell the Sink to use your formatter instead of the default one.

> ### [Formatting Output](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output)
>
> Serilog provides several output formatting mechanisms.
>
> - Formatting plain text
> - Formatting JSON
> - Custom text formatters

Answer (score 2):

With [structured logging](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/06/structured-logging-concepts-in-net-series-1/), the idea is to get away from formulaic formatting of this form (which tends to get parsed with regexes) and instead use meaningful messages.

If you are doing bags or lists of properties like this with Serilog, one technique is to do something like:

```
Log.ForContext("property_name", propertyValue).Information("this is a message")
```

And then ensure you use the `Properties` token in [your `outputTemplate`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#formatting-plain-text), e.g.

```
var mt = "{LogLevel:u3} {SourceContext} {Message:l} {Properties}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

And use that when configuring the Sink:

```
 .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: mt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

you could either do what you do now but with explicitly defined parameters, and get what you ask

`logger.Information("this is a message with property_name = {property_name}", "value");`

or do use a non rendered formatter where

`logger.Information("this is a message with {property_name}", "value");`

will output JSON

```
{
    "message": "this is a message with {property_name}"
    "property_name" : "value"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the name of a Property, the quickest way I can think off is the [CallerMemberName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute).

It is an atribute you apply to the optional string parameter of a function call. It was added only after .NET Framework 4.5. And I think it was pretty much added for this use, in conjunction with INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

The property name string is fundamental to [the Interface working](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged). And the interface is pretty much the basis of MVVM and thus strongly tied to WPF and UWP. And a "Raise Event" function has been standart for decades - sometimes they are even only marked Protected.

As long as that call to the Logging has a function around it, you can easily use it too.

If your question is instead about "how do I overwrite the concatenation rules for this logging System?": String Concatenation. [String.Fomat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) or plain old + operator. If you give it the full string to log in the excact format you want, it can do nothing but give you what you want.